# Removing select rows from display without removing from layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, display, definition-query

I have a layer with a field of image_quality that is marked either good, fine or poor. I also have 4 fields for sediment type: mud, gravel, boulder, outcrop.  I want to display the sediment types together in a pie chart but I only want to display those rows with fine or good images_quality.

Is there a way to exclude the rows with poor image quality from the display without fully removing them from the layer?

I realize I could easily create a new layer of only good and fine image quality but I'd rather keep the entire dataset complete in case I want to include all rows in a future display.

**To summarize: How can I keep select rows from displaying without removing from the layer?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like you just want to use the definition query.  It is simply a SQL-like syntax that you can use on the Definition Query tab found under in the Properties window for the layer.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/displaying-a-subset-of-features-in-a-layer.htm

Your query would be something like:

`"image_quality" = '2' OR "image_quality" = '3'`

given: 1, 2, and 3 for the scale of quality on your photos.

This will only show those images that are their quality 2 OR quality 3 and will display and compute the data as though the other rows do not exist.

Ideally, you should never just throw away your data but filter it.

Comment: This is great advice.  Thank you! I also found that many of the symbology tabs have an exclusion setting built in.  This allowed me to exclude certain data just in that particular symbology.